How to get call back from one window to parent window, when some action performed In SwiftUI/ VisionOs?
Question:
I have contentview, through content view i open Test View.. When Action performed in TestView i need to get call back to contentview?
Main View
@main
struct DemoApp: App {
   var body: some Scene {
       WindowGroup {
           ContentView()
       }

       Window("test", id: Test.self) { $test in
           TestView(test)
        }
    }
}

Content View
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(.openWindow) private var openWindow
    var body: some View {
        Button {
           openWindow(id: "test", for: Test(name: "Window"))
        } label: {
           Text("open text")
        }
    }
}

TestView
struct TestView: View {
    let test: Test
    @Environment(.dismiss) var dismiss
    var body: some View {
         Button {
            // When this button is clicked i need to send the, button clicked to content view
         } label: {
            Text("RECHECK")
         }
    }
}

Test Model
struct Test {
   let name: String
}


Expected Result:
How to Send Closure or any call from the new window to the main window?

Opening a Window is not very suitable for this kind of thing. Have you considered using one of the modal presentation modifiers instead?

@Sweeper, To position the window as per the user's requirement and changing the position in VisionOS, ensure that the window is the specified one. The model presentation is specific to that window only.?

You should say what you want to do in the action because it is quite unusual to not just code the action in the Button closure

Put it on a shared model, the window is irrelevant. The shared source of truth is what matters.

I didn't test this with your code, but typically, if you need the parent view to know something happened in a child view, you'd do so through a binding. The parent view calls child view by passing a state defined in parent, the child views accepts that parameter as a binding, and in your button action, you change the value of the binding, which will change the state in parent. Then, in parent view, you can take action based on the value of that state.

This this link for a simple example.
